# how to customize fields in nested serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, rest

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = JobseekerProfile
        fields = ('user',)
```

*How to modify this fields so that I can add only one field from user like user.username? *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can add ReadOnlyField Field in the serializer. This field only use when you try to retrieve your data. (GET method)

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
   class Meta:
      model = JobseekerProfile
      fields = ('user',)
```

Comment: Thank you ,yes it worked. But I was asking can I directlty insert 'user.username' in fields inside Meta Class fields like this?                                                                                      ```class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = JobseekerProfile
        fields = ('user.username',)```

Comment: can you format your code? then I can understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='user.username')
    class Meta:
        model = JobseekerProfile
        fields = ('user',)
```

Try it